# Replicate an object method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, web

I have a rails engine which uses **current_person** object from the consuming application. The engine calls **current_person.name**.

I need to replicate this object so that i can create a stand alone dummy app for my engine. How do i define **current_person** object in my dummy app so that my engine will correctly pick up **current_person.name** when run from the dummy app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't have a `User` model in the dummy app?

If you just need to access attributes on `current_person`, then you can mock a Person object in your dummy app by using `OpenStruct` (see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html)

For example:

```
def current_person
  OpenStruct.new( name: 'Test User', email: 'somewhere@whatever.xyz' )
end

# usage
current_person.name  # => 'Test User'
```